# Hadoop Pig Remove Strings Not In Like

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm filtering using Pig, and trying to filter by select subsets of a word.  I've tried multiple approaches including NOT MATCHES and !=, also used different wildcard uses such as .*subset*. and %subset% and nothing seems to be working.

I've got terms that look like this:  "26_categoryid%24cat00000" and "43_pcm00023" that I would to filter out (remove). The filter BY day and "is not null" works well.

Here are my three approaches I've tried which have not worked to remove the word subsets:

```
 b = filter a BY day > '2016-02-09
 AND (STRSPLIT(STRSPLIT(attributes, 'term=').$1, '&').$0 is not null)
 AND (NOT STRSPLIT(STRSPLIT(attributes, 'term=').$1, '&').$0 matches  '.*pcm*.')
 AND (NOT STRSPLIT(STRSPLIT(attributes, 'term=').$1, '&').$0 matches '.*category*.');
```

I've also tried this approach:

```
      b = filter a BY day > '2016-02-09
 AND (STRSPLIT(STRSPLIT(attributes, 'term=').$1, '&').$0 is not null)
 AND (STRSPLIT(STRSPLIT(attributes, 'term=').$1, '&').$0 !=  '.*pcm*.')
 AND (STRSPLIT(STRSPLIT(attributes, 'term=').$1, '&').$0 != '.*category*.');
```

And this approach:

```
      b = filter a BY day > '2016-02-09
 AND (STRSPLIT(STRSPLIT(attributes, 'term=').$1, '&').$0 is not null)
 AND (STRSPLIT(STRSPLIT(attributes, 'term=').$1, '&').$0 !=  '%pcm%')
 AND (STRSPLIT(STRSPLIT(attributes, 'term=').$1, '&').$0 != '%category%');
```

Comment: can you give us some dummy data . so that We can run the script on our machine

Comment: @AnkurSingh - i would but it's a huge amount of data and I'm 100% confident the STRSPLIT and finding the correct attribute works

Comment: You should try '.*pcm.*'. You can find more details in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html